# sending emails using asp.net without crashing the application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application for sending emails. I want to make sure that if something goes wrong, then it logs errors and move to next record. I am using SmtpClient class to send emails. but right now, If some email address is wrong, it just crashes. How to force it to move to next record ?

My code is like this:

```
 var EmailsQueue = context.WC_EmailToolQueue.Where(t => t.EmailDate == null).ToList();

            foreach (var email in EmailsQueue)
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SenderEmail);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.Email));
                message.Body = body;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Subject = subject;

                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.Host, 
                    Port = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.Port,  
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SMTPUser, email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SMTPPass), 
                    EnableSsl = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.EnableSSL 
                })
                   try
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {

                }
                }
```

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `try catch` block. If the address is not valid format, the `Add` function will throw an error. If needed you may log it also

```
   try
    {
         message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.Email));
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        //If you want you may log it here
    }
```

**EDIT** : As per the OP's question edit.

the below code will skip sending email to those items having a problem (bad address etc..) But executes the remaining items in loop

```
foreach (var email in EmailsQueue)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    try
    {
        message.From = new MailAddress(email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SenderEmail);
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.Email));            
        message.Body = body;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Subject = subject;

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.Host,
            Port = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.Port,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SMTPUser, email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SMTPPass),
            EnableSsl = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.EnableSSL
        })
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //error in sending email to one item in collection
        //Log it ig you want .Foreach will continue with remaining items    
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing that already but I want that after logging it send email to next record. which it is not doing

Answer (score 2):

Catch the exception using Try/Catch.

```
try
{
    // Send Email code
}
catch (Exception ex) //Or specific exceptions
{
    Log(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I am doing that already but I want that after logging it send email to next record. which it is not doing

Comment: Then you need to post more code including the try/catch so we can direct you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put some logging in the catch block of what you already have. The foreach loop will then carry on to the next record:

```
var EmailsQueue = context.WC_EmailToolQueue.Where(t => t.EmailDate == null).ToList();

    foreach (var email in EmailsQueue)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SenderEmail);
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.Email));
        message.Body = body;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Subject = subject;

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.Host,
            Port = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.Port,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SMTPUser, email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.SMTPPass),
            EnableSsl = email.WC_EmailToolTemplates.EnableSSL
        })
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log the error here <--------
            }
    }
```